# Find, stop and restart a process with bash script

Tags: bash, kill, pi, application-restart

I'm running 'motion' on a Raspberry Pi and need to periodically restart it (or other processes).

```
#!/bin/bash
# find and restart running process motion
sudo kill $(pgrep -f motion)
sleep 5
echo "restarting"
sudo motion -b -c ~/.motion/motion.conf
```

All lines work fine at the command line, but the script stops after successful completion of the 'kill' line.  Same with several other ways of using 'kill' e.g.
ps -ef | grep motion | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill

The word 'Terminated' is just echoed to the screen and script stops.  Is there a right way to find and stop a process in a bash script?

Comment: what is the name of your script?

Comment: Is the word "motion" in the name of the script? Then it will be included in the output of `pgrep -f motion` so it will kill itself.

Comment: Mind, `pgrep`, `pkill`, `ps | grep` &c are sloppy and you shouldn't be writing scripts that use any of them in the first place -- use your distro's process supervisor (typically systemd) and you can just have a timer that restarts `motion.service` without having to know what PID motion.service has.

Comment: (there are other, smaller process supervision systems better suited to tinier embedded systems -- [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/), [s6](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/why.html), [perp](http://b0llix.net/perp/), etc -- but raspbian does afaik use systemd)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you.  'sudo systemctl stop motion' works fine in a bash script.  I believe that's what you meant.

Comment: @Barmar yes, that was it!

Comment: @NigelS, if `systemctl stop motion` works to stop the service, then `systemctl restart motion` will work to perform a restart. (BTW, while the `.service` extension is optional, it can be useful to add it if you add additional types of things named `motion` -- for example, if you have a `motion.timer` and a `motion.mount` in addition to `motion.service`, then just `systemctl stop motion` becomes ambiguous -- at least, to humans trying to figure out which of those systemd units you _meant_ to address).